# C++ - Comparing only time

Tags: c++

Is there a way to only compare time in C++?

For instance, given a array of predefined time (in string, e.g. "04:00", "07:00", "13:00") I want to be able to compare the current time with the range of time given in the array to see which fits.

I have tried `strptime` but I keep getting the undefined error. I have included `time.h` and `stdio.h`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <time.h>

int main() {

    //GET CURRENT TIME
    time_t now = time(0);
    tm *ltm = localtime(&now);
    cout << "Time: "<< ltm->tm_hour << ":";
    cout << ltm->tm_min << ":";
    cout << ltm->tm_sec << endl;

    //TRYING TO CONVERT THE TIME FROM STRING TO PROCEED FOR FURTHER COMPARISON
    struct tm tm;
    std::string s("04:00");
    if (strptime(s.c_str(), "%H:%M", &tm)) { //error strptime is undefined
        int d = tm.tm_mday,
            m = tm.tm_mon + 1,
            y = tm.tm_year + 1900;
        std::cout << y << "-" << m << "-" << d << " "
                  << tm.tm_hour << ":" << tm.tm_min;
    }

    //ATTEMPT TO DO TIME COMPARISON HERE
}
```

Am I missing out on any library?

Is there an easier/alternate way to do this?

Please guide me. Thanks

Comment: I think you are getting confused between c and c++. `cout` is from `<iostream>` header and needs to be prefixed with `std::` unless you have a `using namespace` declaration. You don't need `<ctime>` and `<time.h>`. They provide the same functionality. Just use `<ctime>`. `<time.h>` is for c compatibility. Check [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e8ff80be01432635) it compiles fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timestamps from your example all have the same fixed format: two-digit hours, colon, two-digit minutes.

Which means they are perfectly subject to lexicographic comparison, via `operator<` on `std::string`s, `std::strcmp`, `std::strncmp`, `std::memcmp`, and so forth.

Comment: So you're saying I should just compare the times in string instead without needing to convert it into a time format?

Comment: Sure, why not, if they all follow this pattern.